# Expansions in two small quantities

Tags: linear-algebra

Hopefully this is not too trivial/stupid a question. I have a function

$V = \frac{1 - 3A(1 + \alpha)^2}{B(1+\beta)^{3/2}}$

and I want to make an expansion to first order where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both much smaller than one, and represent more complicated expressions so I wouldn't want to take derivatives with respect to them etc. Is there an obvious definite way this should be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$
(1+\alpha)^2=1+\alpha+O(\alpha^2)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{(1+\beta)^{3/2}}=(1+\beta)^{-3/2}=1-\frac{3}{2}\,\beta+O(\beta^2)
$$